# I can't seem to get through this error in eclipse, programming android app, @drawable?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am programming in Java doing an android app, in my manifest I have an error on my `android:icon=@drawable/icon`. I am not understanding why? Any idea and what causes this error and how to change it?

Comment: Copy and paste your AndroidManifest.xml contents.

Comment: Any time you write the words "I have an error" or "I get an exception", the **very** next thing you should write is the **exact** error or exception message you're receiving. "I have an error" is like saying "I don't feel well" to your doctor - you're not going to get any help without a whole lot more information. Please remember that we can't see your screen from here, and so the only information we have to go by is what you include in your post. If you want help, you need to give us the information that lets us provide it. :)

Comment: I am sure you have written like android:icon="@drawable/icon" in double quote and you are having the icon in drawable folder and there are no any other error in project res folder and you have cleaned it up nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting Error on the lines mentioned by you. then it is something to do with your drawable. drawable is found in the project directory , like Project name->res->drawable. please make sure you kept "icon.png" file there. if not please paste one and clean the project  from Eclipse menu bar(Project->Clean).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your `res/drawable/` folder `icon.png` image exists.You are getting this error due to non-existence of `icon.png` in the `res/drawable/` folder I think.